# What is an unsupported unsolicited response code 11016?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-nexus-s, 3g, data-connection

My UK Nexus S (Android 2.3.2) has real problems sustaining a reliable data connection on 3G even when I have a full signal in London. Connections time out or pages/tweets/whatever load exceptionally slowly and sometimes the green up and down data arrows go grey. The phone works without any problem on WiFi.

I've looked at the radio log using Android System Info and I'm seeing a lot of lines saying:

unsupported unsolicited response code 11016

I've uploaded a log here:

https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0Bz2RssMOCKOIYjkyOTgwNjctZWEzZS00YTBiLWFhYTYtN2MxMjg2ZjQwYzYy&hl=en_GB&authkey=COa-8uAD

which shows a lot of these errors. I wondered if this could be to blame. I've been having these errors for several days in several parts of London. Happy to provide more information if I can.

Many thanks for any thoughts, Tom

Comment: I notice you're on T-Mobile from that log? Are you sure you're not just seeing the problems that a lot of T-Mobile and Orange customers have been seeing after the recent merger, where both networks keep telling your phone that it can freely roam between them, but then keep not connecting you properly to the data services because it keeps switching all the time? Might be worth calling them and checking the problems not at their end (or with the SIM).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's probably best to do a factory reset and see if that helps.  However you could try going to `Settings -> Wireless and network -> Mobile Networks` and experimenting.  I recommend shutting off roaming and making sure Network mode is on Auto.